# Simple Form-Handling djangobook, version 2

Tags: html, django, forms

I am writing a simple search view. My views.py code is

```
def search(request):
     error = False
     if 'q' in request.GET:
          q = request.GET['q']
          if not q:
             error = True
          else:
             books = Book.objects.filter(title__icontains=q)
             return render(request, 'search_results.html', {'books': books, 'query': q})
     return render(request, 'search_form.html', {'error': error})
```

My search_results.html is

```
<p>You searched for: <strong>{{ query }}</strong></p>

{% if books %}
    <p>Found {{ books|length }} book{{ books|pluralize }}.</p>
    <ul>
        {% for book in books %}
        <li>{{ book.title }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No books matched your search criteria.</p>
{% endif %}
```

My search_form.html is

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
{% if error %}
       <p style="color: red;">Please submit a search term.</p>
    {% endif %}
    <form action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="q">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is it is not switching on error = True condition. It is suppose to go to search_form.html in case of error and should reload the search form with error message in red. but it went to search_result.html in both cases.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't quite get u, but I think u should really check your `if` `else` … Maybe that helps.

Comment: i checked many times, in case of error it should reload the search_form.html with error message, but it is showing search_results.html with error message.
I'm a newbie in django, and reading django from djangobook.

Comment: I see nothing wrong in your code, you'll need to debug it, a few tips: print the value of `q` (`print q`) and check the value on the console.. or use [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) and  debug step by step

Answer (score 0):

The django doc explains very well how to work with forms. I think you should read : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/